# Can we omit "with" in the expression glow with (something)?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

I found this in the book [*The Red Badge of Courage*](https://www.pagebypagebooks.com/Stephen_Crane/The_Red_Badge_of_Courage/CHAPTER_I_p2.html) by Stephen Crane:

> - *A folded tent was serving as a roof. The sunlight, without, beating upon it, made it glow a light yellow shade.*

Maybe the expression *glow with (something)* is used here, but omitting *with*?

Comment: I'm curious: why did you write "Peter Lane"? I thought that _The Red Badge of Courage_ was by Stephen Crane.

Comment: Changed on Stephen Crane

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Collins Cobuild English Grammar* [§3.156] lists different semantic classes of verbs that may be used in a depictive 'verb with complement' construction. A classic example of a 'link-like' (ie copular/linking, but also having semantic content, unlike 'be') depictive construction is

- She stood motionless for several seconds.

In the 'have a particular appearance' [my term] semantic subcategory, Collins lists

> - *blush, flame, gleam, glow, run,* [*burn*] [my addition]

and gives examples

> - *They blew into the charcoal until it glowed red*
> - *The trees flamed scarlet against the grass.*
> - [*The roses blushed a deeper red*.] [[Jesse Romero](https://jesseromero.com/blog/his-own-received-him-not)]
> - [*Cook until the juices run clear.*]

[Note that these are depictive, not resultative, usages. Contrast *They blew into the charcoal until it turned red*.]

So

- *The sunlight, beating upon it, made it glow yellow.*

is certainly licensed, but the complement may be legitimately adjusted:

- *The sunlight, beating upon it, made it glow a golden yellow.*
- *The sunlight, beating upon it, made it glow a faint shade of yellow.*

'With' may be used with these nominal complements (some might call them adjuncts), but not with the simple adjectives. However, the variants without the prepositions are probably more idiomatic in general.

[These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glowed+deep+red%2Cglowed+a+deep+red%2Cglowed+a+deep+red+color%2Cglowed+with+a+deep+red&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cglowed%20deep%20red%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglowed%20a%20deep%20red%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglowed%20with%20a%20deep%20red%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cglowed%20deep%20red%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglowed%20a%20deep%20red%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglowed%20with%20a%20deep%20red%3B%2Cc0) give evidence for relative frequencies of use:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> The sunlight … made it glow [with] a light yellow shade".

The short answer is “Yes you can keep or omit *with*.”

“with” can be substituted for “accompanied by” e.g. John left with David.” = John left accompanied by David.

In  *“The sunlight … made it glow **with** a light yellow shade"*,  ***with** a light yellow shade* is an adjunct (a prepositional phrase) modifying “glow”: *and the glowing was accompanied by a light yellow shade.*

> The sunlight … made it glow a light yellow shade".

“a light yellow shade” is not an object: it is the complement of “glow”.

“a light yellow shade” can be classified as

(i) A noun phrase used attributively as a depictive adjective, -> The sunlight … made it glow *and it was a light yellow shade*".
(ii)    A flat adverbial phrase - “The sunlight … made it glow *in the manner of a light yellow shade*".

Comment: If a lady became aware that the world could see her knickers, I think she would just blush [a] bright [shade of] red, or maybe [a] [delicate] pink. I wouldn't really bother using 'with'.